# Centos 8 folder permissions for nginx and sftp user

Tags: nginx, centos, php-fpm, sftp, centos8

I can't figure out how to merge nxginx and sftp user for a folder.

So for example I have folder: `/var/www/domain.com/uploads`

sftp user is: `john`

john belongs to group: `sftpuser`

1. scenario with chown nginx:nginx

from web interface I **can** upload files to `uploads` folder. But the issue that when I login through `sftp` it doesn't have rights to upload any file to that `upload` folder.

2. scenario with chown john:sftpuser

from web interface I **can't** upload files to `uploads` folder. But when I login through `sftp` I am able to upload files to `uploads` folder.

Any ideas and what the proper way to configure this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both scenarios are incorrect.

The only true logical and secure way to run NGINX/PHP-FPM website is by running the website with a separate user (can be your existing SFTP user), and having it own **all** website files and dirs as in `chown example:example` for all files and directories.

See [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be) for more details. Particularly, the important step in this setup is making nginx user to be a member of the website's user group:

```
usermod -a -G example nginx
```

Comment: Thank you will try to follow your guide.